# Looking for symbol made of four quote marks in a square

Tags: symbols

I am looking for this symbol appearing in the original print of Gauss' doctoral dissertation:

[image: dots]

Any suggestions - either for where to find it, or how to "create" it through other ways? I have already looked at "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List".

Note: this symbol is not a sort of relation between 1 and n, but denote a path from 1 to n, in the collected papers of Gauss it's written simply this way: 1...n

Comment: Look for "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List" on CTAN, the list at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols), try at [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: already done...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does this suit you? The comma in Palatino seems to have the desired shape. Some reflection and rotation allow to get the result.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\INVCOMMA}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\usefont{OT1}{ppl}{m}{n},}}
\newcommand{\INVCOMMAP}{\rotatebox{90}{\INVCOMMA}}
\newcommand{\INVCOMMAM}{\rotatebox{-90}{\INVCOMMA}}
\newcommand{\gaussfour}{\mathinner{%
  \ooalign{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\INVCOMMAP}\cr\raisebox{\depth}{\INVCOMMAM}\cr}%
  \mkern2mu
  \ooalign{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\INVCOMMAP}\cr\raisebox{\depth}{\INVCOMMAM}\cr}%
}}

\begin{document}

$i\gaussfour n$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks

Comment: @user6530 You're welcome! Now that I saw your final note, I changed a bit for getting a better spacing.

Comment: That's really nice! +1!

Comment: @Rmano I'm agree with you...wonderful!!!